# Auto expand the element height, if content is bigger in multiple elements css

Tags: html, css

I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/UHrLH/1/

I set the height on the box element to auto, but min-height is 200px;

Now if i try to make more content in the first box, the height expands but it creates a big white space under it. I do not want that, i want to have the box under eachother like you can see above, where the height on all boxes is 200px

See the issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/UHrLH/2/

Comment: The space is because of the `float:left` in `.box`

Comment: @Naven please write as answer and how to do instead?

Comment: Yes I can do that .. but plz clarify if the number of boxes(4) are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/UHrLH/10/

This will give you boxes inline but unfortunately the pairs will not extend to match the height of it's partner. To do this you will need to use tables or a javscript overwrite to capture the height. Also, bear in mind display: inline-block will not work on divs in IE7 and below, it would work on a span though: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UHrLH/11/

I have added an additional `div` if that is ok for you...
`<div class="box_Container">`